# How to set up postgresql from php (beginner)?

Tags: php, postgresql, database-connection

When I try to execute `pg_connect()` in PHP, it does not work and I have come to the realization that my php settings are such that it cannot understand this function, and the php error message reads:

```
Fatal error: "Call to undefined function pg_connect() in test.php on line 11"
```

I have downloaded postgresql with `yum install postgresql-server` in terminal, but nothing more than that.

I have heard from other sources online that I should edit a configuration file, but I don't know where it is.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `extension=php_pgsql.dll` in your php.ini.

Also, enabling `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` would be a good idea too in case you decide to use a PDO in the future.

Comment: Hi! Just did as told, and now I receive a php Warning: "Warning: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/php_pgsql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/modules/php_pgsql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: In fact I looked in this directory and neither of those files were there.

Comment: If you're using linux the extension will be different (`.so`). These packages are packaged with PHP by default so they usually appear in your php.ini already, just with a leading `;`. If you're on linux and you're still missing the extension you can run `apt-get install php5-pgsql`.

Comment: I am indeed in linux, however when I tried to execute that command, however I get the error "bash: apt-get: command not found"

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out that you must edit `php.ini`. That's right for some installs, but only helps if the PostgreSQL interface for PHP is actually present.

On Fedora, that's the `php-pgsql` package:

```
yum install php-pgsql
```

This package will add a file to `/etc/php.d/` which is a directory of `php.ini` snippets.

Just editing `php.ini` without installing the correct package won't help you, and if you install the package you don't need to edit `php.ini`.

In any case, **please just use PDO**. The PostgreSQL extension for PHP isn't well maintained these days, and the strong push toward PDO is likely to make your life harder over time.

Answer (score 0):

Enable php_pgsql in your server. Click on your WAMP (if its WAMP server)->PHP->PHP extensions->php_pgsql (click on it).